# How to have just one pre-requisite check in TestNG for multiple tests distributed across classes

Tags: java, test-automation-framework, testng

I have a Test Automation project using TestNg.

I want to make sure certain configurations are enabled before I start some of the tests. I have written this as a test and marked other tests as dependent on this. So I have used the TestNG param "dependsOnMethods" for all the individual tests which are dependent on this check.

These tests are distributed across multiple classes and I currently have to do this check in each and every class, which works fine if all tests are passing, but if there is a configuration missing, I get a bunch of errors because the test which is doing this check fails and then I have a copy of this failure in almost every class I have.

So instead of 1 failure, I end up with 10 failures, as this failure happens multiple times.

This can't be a @BeforeTest or @BeforeMethod or @BeforeClass since this is required for only a few of the tests in a TestClass.

I can set a Global Flag based on the failure of this test, but then again I can't skip Testng tests based on Flags. So I will get false Negatives.

Is there a way to create a test in a parent class and skip some tests if this fails?

Comment: I think this might help. I'll check and update the results here - https://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/skip-test-in-testng

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if one has to skip tests based on a boolean you can use SkipException. This helps when we don't want to depend on a method call using `dependsOnMethods` param of TestNg

```
@Test()
public void testDependingOnData {
  if(dataMissing) {
     throw new SkipException("We skip this Test");
  }
  // Test Steps here
}
```

This article helped me with the solution - https://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/skip-test-in-testng

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if TestNG allows to have a common `dependsOnMethods` for multiple classes.

You can try another option called `dependsOnGroups`.

[Here](https://www.journaldev.com/21389/testng-dependency-dependsonmethods-dependsongroups) is an article to help you with it. As I am not aware of the copyrights of the content of the reference article. I am only giving a link rather than copying the content here.

You can also try out solutions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7692129/testng-dependsonmethods-from-different-class).

Answer (score -1):

By using grouping. You can create a group of tasks you want to execute and then make a suite for it and only those test cases will run. 2. By using enable and disable in the test method such that only the test case where enabled = true will execute and the test methods with enabled = false will not.

Comment: Alwin, thank you for taking the time to answer this question. I would like to point out that links unrelated to the question / answer are not permitted. Links related to the question are permitted, as long as the question is not link-only and provided if there is any promotion for which you benefit it is both relevant and disclosed as such in the post. Thank you!